# TypeError: Failed to fetch swagger ui issue

Tags: api, swagger

I am new with swagger and i am experiencing some problem with it.I've run a server for the swagger and additional for the dummy data that you can generate from the swagger but both are not connected somehow.

I am getting this error[image]

also this is the error i am getting when i do so:
[image]

I know this issue is with CORS and i've read all docs provided:

[cors git](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/cors.md)

[Crossover with git -cors](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1888)

a link from SO with similar issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

and i am still not able to fix my issue!

Please advise,

Darko

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
I found a solution to my problem. What basically what was i doing was testing the problem on a wrong server the swagger local editor and i needed to test it on the swagger tester. Sorry for the inconvenience i solved my problem by just testing it on the local swagger ui that is provided by the swagger server.